# .htaccess redirect with question mark

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying this to redirect via .htaccess a this URL

`http://www.deguate.com/foros/showthread.php?874-Soy-de-Guatemala-y-quiero-dar-a-mi-bebe-en-adopcion`

to this one:

`https://www.deguate.com/artman/publish/mujer-actualidad/Soy-de-Guatemala-quiero-dar-mi-bebe-adopcion.shtml`

I've tried many options but nothing seems to work, like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^foros\/showthread\.php\?874\-Soy\-de\-Guatemala\-y\-quiero\-dar\-a\-mi\-bebe\-en\-adopcion$ "https\:\/\/www\.deguate\.com\/artman\/publish\/mujer\-actualidad\/Soy\-de\-Guatemala\-quiero\-dar\-mi\-bebe\-adopcion\.shtml" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(874-Soy-de-Guatemala-y-quiero-dar-a-mi-bebe-en-adopcion)$
RewriteRule ^foros/showthread\.php$ https://www.deguate.com/artman/publish/mujer-actualidad/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hello Starkeen, this ALMOST worked, but it's redirecting me to:

https://www.deguate.com/artman/publish/mujer-actualidad/874-Soy-de-Guatemala-y-quiero-dar-a-mi-bebe-en-adopcion

It should be:

https://www.deguate.com/artman/publish/mujer-actualidad/Soy-de-Guatemala-quiero-dar-mi-bebe-adopcion.shtml

(The new filename is NOT exactly the same!)

Comment: Hello again, I was able to redirect to the page I needed by changing a little bit what you wrote above like this:  
  
    RewriteEngine on  

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(874-Soy-de-Guatemala-y-quiero-dar-a-mi-bebe-en-adopcion)$  
    RewriteRule ^foros/showthread\.php$ https://www.deguate.com/artman/publish/mujer-actualidad/Soy-de-Guatemala-quiero-dar-mi-bebe-adopcion.shtml [L,R]  
  
This works, BUT it shows ?874-Soy-de-Guatemala-y-quiero-dar-a-mi-bebe-en-adopcion at the end of the URL. Not that I care much but it would be great to remove that portion :)

Comment: The QueryString is appearing in your destination url because you are not using `?` (an empty question mark) at the end of the Rewrite destination url. See the final `?` in my rule `RewriteRule ^foros/showthread\.php$ https://www.deguate.com/artman/publish/mujer-actualidad/%1? [L,R]` .